What is difference between nibbana and deep sleep?
In sleep 5 sense door are closed. And in deep sleep tge mind door is also closed. So technically its nibbana. Isnt it?

Deep sleep is not Nibbana when the mind still has underlying tendencies (anusayā) which have not been uprooted (samugghātaṁ). In Nibbana, the underlying tendencies have been uprooted & permanently destroyed.

Thinking that way and sleeping a deep deep sleep, your job may soon become fully extinguished as you fail to show up to do what needs to be done.

DN16:3.7.4: ‘Wicked One, I shall not become fully extinguished until I have monk disciples who are competent, educated, assured, learned, have memorized the teachings, and practice in line with the teachings. Not until they practice properly, living in line with the teaching. Not until they’ve learned their tradition, and explain, teach, assert, establish, disclose, analyze, and make it clear. Not until they can legitimately and completely refute the doctrines of others that come up, and teach with a demonstrable basis.’


No, fabrications still operate in deep sleep, but not in nibbāna, which is taught by the Buddha to be an unfabricated state. People can still have lustful dreams in deep sleep, but those who have attained nibbāna have completely destroyed passion - so from what would such dreams arise?

By the way there is no dream in deep sleep state. If one is dreaming its called REM sleep. We generally are in deep sleep state for 30 min or so. and altogether 2 hour or so.

obviously there are no fabrications in deep sleep (except when dreams occur, which only happen for a small minority time in deep sleep).

So do you think the bodily fabrications - breathing - stop in deep sleep?

@enRaiser imo if you don't remember dreaming at all you are in deep sleep

i read that deep sleep is only ignorance and bliss, so maybe DD is right, without fabrication...what is the purpose of fabricating in deep sleep?  body fabrication is of no concern since u r not your body, u r not your consciousness either, but if i was i wouldn't know
